# IFTTT, Send an image from Dropbox to Telegram

Tags: dropbox, telegram, ifttt

On IFTTT I am trying to build an applet that monitors a dropbox folder specified by the user, the trigger is adding a new image to the folder; then the image shall be sent to a telegram group chosen by the user.

I built it as best as I can; I keep adding new images but nothing happens.

I did a test to see if the connection with Dropbox is fine, so I changed the trigger to "adding text file", if True then send a message with a defined text to telegram, it worked.

Then I did the same with "adding photo" as a trigger, then nothing happens.
This makes me think the issue is with dropbox detecting new images. Are there special conditions?!
Images I am using are BMP, jpg, and png

[image: IFTTT - Applet Design 01]

[image: IFTTT - Applet Design 02]

[image: IFTTT - Applet Design 03]

[image: Applet setting and checking activity]

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox new photo in a folder service is broken since last year and I don't think the have fixed it yet. You can use "New file in folder" instead.